# Cannot configure login script for a webpage

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to add a login functionality to my website. But there is some issue with binding login details and database entries. The program successfully accesses DB and stores login attempts in the `login_attempts` table of DB, but all the time says `Error Logging In`, though the password that I write in the login form coincides with the one from DB table `members` (the decoded one). In particular, the line `if ($db_password == $password)` in the `includes/functions.php` returns false. I cannot figure out why does it happen. I tried to not use the encoding, but the problem is the same. What is wrong there?

**index.php**

```
<?php
include_once 'includes/db_connect.php';
include_once 'includes/functions.php';

sec_session_start();

if (login_check($mysqli) == true) {
    $logged = 'in';
} else {
    $logged = 'out';
}
?>

<html class=" -webkit- -webkit-"><head>
<body>
        <?php
        if (isset($_GET['error'])) {
            echo '<p class="error">Error Logging In!</p>';
        }
        ?>
    <div class="wrapper">
  <form class="login" action="includes/process_login.php" method="post" name="login_form">
    <input type="text" placeholder="GroupId" autofocus="" name="username">
    <i class="fa fa-user"></i>
    <input type="password" placeholder="Password" name="password" id="password">
    <i class="fa fa-key"></i>
    <a href='register.php'>Register</a>
    <button onclick="formhash(this.form, this.form.password);">
      <i class="spinner"></i>
      <span class="state">Log in</span>
    </button>
  </form>
</div>
    <script src="js/prefixfree.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="js/index.js"></script>
    <script type="text/JavaScript" src="js/sha512.js"></script>
    <script type="text/JavaScript" src="js/forms.js"></script>    
</body></html>
```

**includes/process_login.php**

```
<?php
include_once 'db_connect.php';
include_once 'functions.php';

sec_session_start(); // A custom secure way of starting a PHP session.

if (isset($_POST['username'], $_POST['password'])) {
    $username = $_POST['username'];
    $password = $_POST['password']; // The hashed password.

    if (login($username, $password, $mysqli) == true) {
        // Login success
        header('Location: ../protected_page.php');
    } else {
        // Login failed
        header('Location: ../index.php?error=1');
    }
} else {
    // The correct POST variables were not sent to this page.
    echo 'Invalid Request';
}
```

**includes/functions.php**

```
<?php
include_once 'psl-config.php';

function sec_session_start() {
    $session_name = 'sec_session_id';   // Set a custom session name
    $secure = SECURE;
    // This stops JavaScript being able to access the session id.
    $httponly = true;
    // Forces sessions to only use cookies.
    if (ini_set('session.use_only_cookies', 1) === FALSE) {
        header("Location: ../error.php?err=Could not initiate a safe session (ini_set)");
        exit();
    }
    // Gets current cookies params.
    $cookieParams = session_get_cookie_params();
    session_set_cookie_params($cookieParams["lifetime"],
        $cookieParams["path"],
        $cookieParams["domain"],
        $secure,
        $httponly);
    // Sets the session name to the one set above.
    session_name($session_name);
    session_start();            // Start the PHP session
    session_regenerate_id(true);    // regenerated the session, delete the old one.
}

function login($username, $password, $mysqli) {
    // Using prepared statements means that SQL injection is not possible.
    if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT id, email, password, salt
        FROM members
       WHERE username = ?
        LIMIT 1")) {
        $stmt->bind_param('s', $username);  // Bind "$username" to parameter.
        $stmt->execute();    // Execute the prepared query.
        $stmt->store_result();

        // get variables from result.
        $stmt->bind_result($user_id, $email, $db_password, $salt);
        $stmt->fetch();

        // hash the password with the unique salt.
        $password = hash('sha512', $password . $salt);
        if ($stmt->num_rows == 1) {
            // If the user exists we check if the account is locked
            // from too many login attempts

            if (checkbrute($user_id, $mysqli) == true) {
                // Account is locked
                // Send an email to user saying their account is locked
                return false;
            } else {
                // Check if the password in the database matches
                // the password the user submitted.
                if ($db_password == $password) {
                    // Password is correct!
                    // Get the user-agent string of the user.
                    $user_browser = $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];
                    // XSS protection as we might print this value
                    $user_id = preg_replace("/[^0-9]+/", "", $user_id);
                    $_SESSION['user_id'] = $user_id;
                    // XSS protection as we might print this value
                    $username = preg_replace("/[^a-zA-Z0-9_\-]+/",
                                                                "",
                                                                $username);
                    $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
                    $_SESSION['login_string'] = hash('sha512',
                              $password . $user_browser);
                    // Login successful.
                    return true;
                } else {
                    // Password is not correct
                    // We record this attempt in the database
                    $now = time();
                    $mysqli->query("INSERT INTO login_attempts(user_id, time)
                                    VALUES ('$user_id', '$now')");
                    return false;
                }
            }
        } else {
            // No user exists.
            return false;
        }
    }
    }

    function checkbrute($user_id, $mysqli) {
    // Get timestamp of current time
    $now = time();

    // All login attempts are counted from the past 2 hours.
    $valid_attempts = $now - (2 * 60 * 60);

    if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT time
                             FROM login_attempts
                             WHERE user_id = ?
                            AND time > '$valid_attempts'")) {
        $stmt->bind_param('i', $user_id);

        // Execute the prepared query.
        $stmt->execute();
        $stmt->store_result();

        // If there have been more than 10 failed logins
        if ($stmt->num_rows > 10) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
}

function login_check($mysqli) {
    // Check if all session variables are set
    if (isset($_SESSION['user_id'],
                        $_SESSION['username'],
                        $_SESSION['login_string'])) {

        $user_id = $_SESSION['user_id'];
        $login_string = $_SESSION['login_string'];
        $username = $_SESSION['username'];

        // Get the user-agent string of the user.
        $user_browser = $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];

        if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT password
                                      FROM members
                                      WHERE id = ? LIMIT 1")) {
            // Bind "$user_id" to parameter.
            $stmt->bind_param('i', $user_id);
            $stmt->execute();   // Execute the prepared query.
            $stmt->store_result();

            if ($stmt->num_rows == 1) {
                // If the user exists get variables from result.
                $stmt->bind_result($password);
                $stmt->fetch();
                $login_check = hash('sha512', $password . $user_browser);

                if ($login_check == $login_string) {
                    // Logged In!!!!
                    return true;
                } else {
                    // Not logged in
                    return false;
                }
            } else {
                // Not logged in
                return false;
            }
        } else {
            // Not logged in
            return false;
        }
    } else {
        // Not logged in
        return false;
    }
}

function esc_url($url) {

    if ('' == $url) {
        return $url;
    }

    $url = preg_replace('|[^a-z0-9-~+_.?#=!&;,/:%@$\|*\'()\\x80-\\xff]|i', '', $url);

    $strip = array('%0d', '%0a', '%0D', '%0A');
    $url = (string) $url;

    $count = 1;
    while ($count) {
        $url = str_replace($strip, '', $url, $count);
    }

    $url = str_replace(';//', '://', $url);

    $url = htmlentities($url);

    $url = str_replace('&amp;', '&#038;', $url);
    $url = str_replace("'", '&#039;', $url);

    if ($url[0] !== '/') {
        // We're only interested in relative links from $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']
        return '';
    } else {
        return $url;
    }
}
```

Comment: **WARNING**: Writing your own access control layer is not easy and there are many opportunities to get it severely wrong. Please, do not write your own authentication system when any modern [development framework](http://codegeekz.com/best-php-frameworks-for-developers/) like [Laravel](http://laravel.com/) comes with a robust [authentication system](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/authentication) built-in. At the absolute least follow [recommended security best practices](http://www.phptherightway.com/#security) and never store passwords without hashing them properly. SHA512 is not sufficient.

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using [parameterized queries](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **DO NOT** use string interpolation or concatenation to accomplish this because you have created a severe [SQL injection bug](http://bobby-tables.com/). **NEVER** put `$_POST` or `$_GET` data directly into a query, it can be very harmful if someone seeks to exploit your mistake.

Comment: @WARNING: How to integrate Lavarel into an existing website?

Comment: It's more it's own thing, so it's more a case of wrangling your existing code into a good MVC framework like Laravel offers.